# How to install Cordova on Ubuntu 14.04 to develop hybrid apps?

Tags: 14.04, android

I want to install Cordova on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I want to convert my web application to android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova Installation:

Add the Ubuntu Cordova [Personal Package Archive](https://launchpad.net/~cordova-ubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cordova-ubuntu/ppa  
sudo apt-get update
```

Install cordova-cli package (and its dependencies):

```
sudo apt-get install cordova-cli
```

Project Workflow:

Create a project

```
cordova create project1 REVERSEDNSNAME.project1 project1
```

Move into the Project Directory:

```
cd project1
```

Add the android platform:

```
cordova platform add android
```

Create an Andorid emulator

```
android create avd -n hello -t 1
```

Run the cordova app on the emulator :

```
cordova emulate android
```

Reference [here for android](http://chrislarson.me/blog/how-use-cordova-ubuntu-build-android-apps.html)

For reference [here for Ubuntu](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_ubuntu_index.md.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I want to add platform for android .. (not ubuntu)!

Comment: I think we should use "$ cordova platform add android" instead of ..ubuntu!

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid]

Answer (score 0):

To install Cordova on Ubuntu,  run :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cordova-ubuntu/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cordova-cli
```

---

You can test your environment by creating a sample application :

```
cordova create myapp com.ubuntu.developer.myid.myapp "My App"
cd myapp
cordova platform add ubuntu
```

And finally build your application by running :

```
cordova build --device
```

---

Refer to [Ubuntu Developer Page on Cordova](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/guides/cordova-guide/) and the [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_ubuntu_index.md.html) for more infomations.