# error for cordova build ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

I've successfully built app for Android in Cordova in Ubuntu 14.04. However, I got error while I was trying to run Cordova build Ubuntu in project folder, which is as following,

```
Running command: /home/sachin/myapp/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build 
Building Desktop Application...
Missing icon
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/sachin/myapp/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/sachin/myapp/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/share/cordova-cli/_vendor/cordova-lib/5.3.1/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

How to resolve these errors?

Comment: refer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672416/how-to-install-cordova-on-ubuntu-14-04-to-develop-hybrid-apps/672421#672421)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Install Cordova:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cordova-ubuntu/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cordova-cli
```

**Create a project:**

```
cordova create project1 REVERSEDNSNAME.project1 project1
cd project1
```

**Add Ubuntu to the platform:**

```
cordova platform add ubuntu
cordova build ubuntu
cordova run ubuntu
```

Reference [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_ubuntu_index.md.html)

Comment: hi, i could able to reach till 'cordova platform add ubuntu', but when i run 'cordova build ubuntu', i get bellow error   "You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project".  I am trying run this on my "ubuntu-emultor".. Do i need to make any specific settings for this?

Comment: try this : run `cordova build` then `cordova build ubuntu`

Comment: not working.. For android we do something like "add the SDK to your path
PATH=$PATH:", whether we need do something like this for ubuntu?

Comment: I think it is better ,if you edit your question and add the error for `cordova build ubuntu`, and also refer [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/guides/cordova-guide/)

Comment: hi, is there any SDK path related setting we need to do? helpful if you can share a link of some sample projects??

Comment: try `cordova -d run ubuntu`...any change?

Comment: Refer [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/tutorials/cordova-camera-app-tutorial/) and [here](http://proyectojuanchacon.blogspot.in/2015/01/apache-cordova-development-environment.html) and [here](http://www.gaggl.com/2014/04/apache-cordova-development-environment-install-on-ubuntu/).Probably the first link may help you more.....then comment

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same error message (Ubuntu 15.10). I found some information about it on a different web page:

http://resolvinghere.com/sof/30229535.shtml

According to that answer, there seems to be a bug in the repository used. To fix this partcular issue, it is advised to add the latest platform release directly (after removing the old one):

```
$ cordova platform remove ubuntu 
$ cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-ubuntu
```

This actually solved the compiling error for me. It even suggests to build a debian package:

```
$ cordova build ubuntu
Building...
Note: to build a debian package, run:
[...]
```

I hope that this approach fixes the issue for most people. Personally, I cannot run the empty application. The window shows up, but remains white and the application hangs.